# SQLBroker: how to clean conversation timers?

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I am testing scheduled jobs suggested by Mladen Prajdić here many years ago:

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/scheduling-jobs-in-sql-server-express-2

He uses SQL Broker conversation timers to work with scheduled jobs.
I see that non-activate timers still exists in `sys.conversation_endpoints` with

```
dialog_timer = 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

But after some time there will be more and more records with not used endpoints.

Ok, questions: 
1. Do I need somehow to clean up non-active conversation timers? 
2. How to do it?

Comment: what you have are pending conversation endpoints, it seems you are not ending dialogs.. IIRC a conversation timer is just an attribute of the conversation, it's not an entity by itself... the column **dialog_timer** is not nullable in [sys.conversation_endpoints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176082.aspx) so it defaults to the minimum value...

Comment: yes, you are right. Sometimes dialogs were not ended